# Movie with car driving into orange web

Tags: story-identification

I have a very loose recollection of a film where a car, driven by a man with another male passenger, crashes into a orange web and gets stuck.

I also remember other parts of the film involve infiltrating some sort of 'futuristic' compound and talking to a floating head of some sort.

Sorry the details are really hazy!

Comment: When did the movie look to be from? Not an exact date obviously, but from the visual style (and when you saw it) you may be able to narrow it down to something like "70s/early 80s" or "2000s" or whatever.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I think it was around 80s/early 90s

Comment: Futuristic compound and floating head make me think "Zardoz," but I'm not sure that had an orange web.

Comment: @Jonah No, it's not 'Zardoz'